# Получение значения статического поля с помощью рефлексии

Tags: java, рефлексия

Есть статическое поле

```
public static final class Util {
    public static final int VALUE = 20000;
}
```

Как узнать его значение, используя reflection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.out.println(Util.class.getDeclaredField("VALUE").get(null));
```